# Creating the same event for 2 different elements in jQuery (not for each one, for both!)

Tags: jquery, html

I'd like to create a toggle event for 2 different TD's in my table row.
the event should show / hide the next table row.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td> <td>2</td> <td>3</td> <td>4</td> <td>5</td> <td class="clickable1">6</td> <td class="clickable2">7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>this row should be toggled between show/hide once one of the clickable TDs were clicked</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here's the code I tried to apply but it has applied each one of the classes the event:

```
$('.clickable1,.clickable2').toggle(function() {
    $(this).parent()
       .next('tr')
       .show();
}, function() {
$(this).parent()
       .next('tr')
       .hide();
});
```

One more thing: I'm applying on each TR a CSS hover psuedo class. how can I make the two TRs to be highlighted (like hover effect on two of them) ?

Here's what I've found to be working perfectly so far:

```
$('.clickable1,.clickable2').click(function() {
   $(this).parent()
          .next('tr')
          .toggle();
});
```

It seems that the TR remembers it's previous state by the toggle command!

Comment: You should create an answer and mark it as valid. Otherwise this question keeps appearing on the "Unanswered questions" list.

Comment: ok i just added the answer
how do i mark it as valid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for all the answers guys! 
here's what i've found to be working perfectly so far:

```
$('.clickable1,.clickable2').click(function() {
                       $(this).parent()
                              .next('tr')
                              .toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than use a toggle handler, just toggle visibility based on button click.  Use toggleClass to switch the "hover" class in and out.

```
$('.clickable1,.clickable2').click(function() {
     var parent = $(this).parent();
     parent.toggleClass('hovered');

     var next = parent.next('tr');
     next.toggle().toggleClass('hovered');
});
```

Comment: This is a great solution given the assumption that the show/hide was the only functionality required for the toggle.

Answer (score 1):

If you really only want one event, one option would be to place the handler on the parent container, and rely on the automatic bubbling to trigger it.

You could normally use jQuery's `delegate()` function, but I don't think it supports the `toggle` event.

```
$('tr:has([class^=clickable])').toggle(function(e) {

        // Verify that the target had a clickable class
    if($(e.target).closest('[class^=clickable]').length ) {

            // No need to call .parent() since the handler is now on the <tr>
        $(this).next('tr').show();
    }
},
function(e) {

        // Verify that the target had a clickable class
    if($(e.target).closest('[class^=clickable]').length ) {

            // No need to call .parent() since the handler is now on the <tr>
        $(this).next('tr').hide();
    }
});
```

Alternatively, you could just have one fire the other.

```
$('.clickable1').toggle(function() {
        $(this).parent()
           .next('tr')
           .show();
    }, function() {
    $(this).parent()
           .next('tr')
           .hide();
    });

$('.clickable2').click(function() {
    $(this).prev().click();     // Fires the click event for its previous sibling
});
```

---

For the hover, this would be one approach.

```
$('tr:has([class^=clickable]):even').hover(
  function() {
      $(this).addClass('hilite')
      .next().addClass('hilite');
  },
  function() {
      $(this).removeClass('hilite')
      .next().removeClass('hilite');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

[Check this jsFiddle out](http://jsfiddle.net/V8AKL/) that demos both requested behaviors.  Note that I changed the classes clickable1 and clickable2 to just clickable since I didn't see any reason in your example to have two classes.  That can be changed back with minor tweaks if you want.  The code is also included below in case jsFiddle dies:

HTML:

```
<table id="table">
<tr>
<td>1</td> <td>2</td> <td>3</td> <td>4</td> <td>5</td> <td class="clickable">6</td> <td class="clickable">7</td>
</tr>
<tr class="toggleVis"><td colspan="7">this row should be toggled between show/hide once one of the clickable TDs were clicked</td></tr>
</table>​
```

CSS:

```
.clickable{cursor:pointer;}
.hide{display:none;}
.hover{font-weight:bold;border:solid 1px blue;background-color:yellow;}​
```

jQuery:

```
$(".clickable").click(function() {
    $(".toggleVis").toggleClass("hide");
});
$('tr', "#table").hover(
    function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("hover");
    },
    function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("hover");
    });
```

Comment: Respectfully, this doesn't quite work. First, remember that the OP may have reasons for the two different classes beyond the event handling. Second, your click handler will toggle *all* elements with the class `.toggleVis`, while OP just wants to toggle the next row (pretty safe assumption that he has several row pairs). Third, for the row hilighting on hover, OP wants to hilight each row with its pair (the one that would be hidden on the click event).

Answer (score 0):

Why couldn't you just do this?

```
$('.clickable1,.clickable2').click(function(e){
    var nTR=$(e.target).parent().next('tr');
    if (nTR.css("display")!="none") nTR.hide();
    else nTR.show();
});​​​​​​
```

Also, you might want to
[take a look at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547564/jquery-toggle-doesnt-work-properly-on-two-different-elements).

As for the psuedo-class on the TRs, you're going to have to use another event handler for that, since it's a custom behavior.  Luckily, that's pretty easy:

```
$("tr").hover(function(){
  $(this).next('tr').andSelf()
     .css("backgroundColor","#F00");},
  function(){$(this).next('tr').andSelf()
     .css("backgroundColor","#FFF");
});
```